# Substitute a variable in PHP expression with its value

Tags: php, substr

It is simple thing but I cannot resolve it myself.

I am trying to extract part of a string using substr:

`$Text=substr($FullText, 0, 6);`

Where $FullText is a varaible containing a string.

I guess substr does not like variable and needs a string in quotas.

My question is how can I substitute variable in PHP expression with its value?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: `substr` likes variables. Please add a concrete example to obtain useful help.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to output? And what's your input. Please clarify these first.

Comment: Please provide a specific example..... what is the value of `$FullText`? What do you expect? What do you get? [Demo](https://3v4l.org/0tn56)

Comment: `$FullText=$ExchangePart->Item(5)->nodeValue; //actual value of the variable is: "1.6598 6.479460 5.4545"
$Text=substr($FullText, 0, 6);
//$Text=$ExchangePart->Item(5)->nodeValue;
echo $Text;`

Comment: @Rat2good Why don't you try echoing $FullText first to see if there's actually anything in it, before you try to get its substring.

Comment: [Demo](https://3v4l.org/rCShO) so what is the actual value being echoed from `$Text`? If it isn't `1.6598` then `$ExchangePart->Item(5)->nodeValue` isn't returning what you think it is

Comment: @frosty When I am echoing the $FullText it returns 1.6500 1.8080 2.3860

Comment: @Rat2good Yeah, try converting it to string first.

Comment: $FullText = (string)$FullText;

Answer (score 0):

```
$text=substr($fulltext, 0, 6);
```

it will work, Substr function receives string in double quotes or you can put php variable in it. Try to echo this, it will work as required

Comment: it des not work unfortunately... it works if I write something like: `$text=substr("abcdefgh", 0, 6);` it will return abcdef but when I use a variable it does not work

Comment: @Rat2good What do you mean by not working? What is the output?

Comment: there is no output when I echoing $text;

Comment: @Rat2good Then show us the full code, instead of just partial.

Comment: @Rat2good, could you try running `$input="abcdefgh"; $text=substr($input, 0, 6);`? There really is no reason it shouldn't be working with a variable.

Comment: @frosty I have echoed $text it works now, returned "abcdef" but does not work in my case when the value of the $FullText is 1.6500 1.8080 2.3860.

Comment: I think @frosty's solution is probably correct, but if that doesn't work could you provide the output of `echo var_dump($FullText);`?

Comment: Does not work...                        `$FullText=$ExchangePart->Item(5)->nodeValue;
$FullText = (string)$FullText;
echo $FullText;
$Text=substr($FullText, 0, 6);
echo $Text;`  the code returns 1.6500 1.8080 2.3860 but not 1.6500 I am expecting

Comment: @Chris the result of var_dump is: string(54) " 1.6500 1.8080 2.3860 "

Comment: @Rat2good, it looks like you have extraneous spaces on your input. The output is probably there it will just be spaces. Please try `$FullText=$ExchangePart->Item(5)->nodeValue; $FullText = trim($FullText); $Text=substr($FullText, 0, 6); echo $Text;`

Comment: Chris Thank you very much! It works now! People, you are great!

Comment: @frosty Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You posted this code fragment in a comment to the question:

```
$FullText=$ExchangePart->Item(5)->nodeValue;
//actual value of the variable is: "1.6598 6.479460 5.4545"
$Text=substr($FullText, 0, 6);
//$Text=$ExchangePart->Item(5)->nodeValue;
echo $Text;
```

It looks like you are handling XML here. The [`SimpleXMLElement`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php) class (the type of the objects created by the [`simplexml_*()` functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.simplexml.php)) is a beast with many faces. If you try to:

```
echo($ExchangePart->Item(5)->nodeValue);
```

or

```
print_r($ExchangePart->Item(5)->nodeValue);
```

it is presented as a string but, in fact, it is also an `SimpleXMLElement` object.

The solution to the issue is very simple: you have to [explicitly convert](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php#language.types.typecasting) the value you want to a string:

```
$FullText = (string)$ExchangePart->Item(5)->nodeValue;
```

Now the value of `$FullText` is a string; you can safely pass it to any string processing function and it will work as described in the documentation.